# How to locate react-leaflet map to user's current position and get the borders for this map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I need to locate react-leaflet map to user's current position and get the borders for this map. I tried to apply the following code, but faced the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'locate' of undefined (anonymous
> function)

Please help me!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import restaurantsInfo from "./RestaurantsList.json";
import "./App.css";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import { Icon, latLng } from "leaflet";
import Restaurants from "./Restaurants.js";
import LocationMarker from "./LocationMarker.js";
import L from 'leaflet';

const myLocation = [49.1951, 16.6068];
const defaultZoom = 13;

export default function App() {

  const mapRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const { current = {} } = mapRef;
    const { leafletElement: map } = current;
    map.locate({
    setView: true,
    });
    map.on('locationfound', handleOnLocationFound);
  }, []);

  function handleOnLocationFound(event) {
    const { current = {} } = mapRef;
    const { leafletElement: map } = current;
    const latlng = event.latlng;
    const radius = event.accuracy;
    const circle = L.circle(latlng, radius);
    circle.addTo(map);
  }

  return (
    <div class="container">
    <div style={{height: '400px', width: '500px'}} class="map">
    
    <MapContainer ref={mapRef} center={myLocation} zoom={defaultZoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
< /MapContainer >
```

Comment: you can get ther bounds of the map with `map.getBounds()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a custom component that will do that job and will be child of `MapContainer`. Get the bounding box from `locationfound` `event.bounds`

```
 function LocationMarker() {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);
    const [bbox, setBbox] = useState([]);

    const map = useMap();

    useEffect(() => {
      map.locate().on("locationfound", function (e) {
        setPosition(e.latlng);
        map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
        const radius = e.accuracy;
        const circle = L.circle(e.latlng, radius);
        circle.addTo(map);
        setBbox(e.bounds.toBBoxString().split(","));
      });
    }, [map]);

    return position === null ? null : (
      <Marker position={position} icon={icon}>
        <Popup>
          You are here. <br />
          Map bbox: <br />
          <b>Southwest lng</b>: {bbox[0]} <br />
          <b>Southwest lat</b>: {bbox[1]} <br />
          <b>Northeast lng</b>: {bbox[2]} <br />
          <b>Northeast lat</b>: {bbox[3]}
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    );
  }
```

Use it here

```
<MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      ...
      <LocationMarker />
 </MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-locate-react-leaflet-v3x-map-to-users-current-position-and-get-the-borders-for-this-map-g1onh)

Comment: Ohh, great it works, thank you!!! 

I have one more question. How can I use bbox to check If some of my markers is inside the map?
When I try to apply:

 if (bbox.contains(marker.getPosition())===true)

or this 

if ((bbox[1] < marker.lat< bbox[3])&&
     (bbox[2] <marker.long <bbox[4]))

I got the error:  bbox is not defined

I don’t know how to return bbox from function LocationMarker().

Comment: Please accept the answer since it solved your issue. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are new to SO. Regarding your question please ask in a new thread as it a new question regarding your original post and I will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new and my new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509189/how-to-get-borders-for-the-react-leaflet-map-and-check-markers-inside-the-map

Comment: for me raises this: Cannot convert undefined or null to object